# Google Map Api V3 dont display after hosting change

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, hosting

I'm newbie to JavaScript and Google Maps API. I do some maps for my clients websites - my last map was a kind of store locator with customs markers - and I use the version 3 of Google API, Sensor set to false, and I don't use API KEY.

I can't figure out why after change of hosting the map does not show at all. The script seems to load but just a blank box is displayed, in first hosting work like a charm but the second doesn't work, the first is Linux Apache and the second is Windows IIS, I don't think that the problems is due to the use of Windows because it is a page with static HTML and CSS with dynamic Google Map.

This is the site Working on first hosting  http://ofimatic.com.ni/blandonmoreno/

This is the site with no map working http://www.blandonmoreno.com/home.html

Why does the same code not work on other hosting? The new hosting has multiple sites same IP, and all use Google Maps. Could that be the problem? I can't see a tag saying I pass the usage limit of Google Maps API. Do I need to use API key?

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple.

- Go to the [google api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
- Navigate to the **API Access** tab
- Find this "**Client ID for web applications**" section for your project
- Click on "**Edit client settings**"
- You will see a popup window with current project settings
  [image: Edit client settings window]
- Change the **JavaScript Origins** to the new once ( http://ofimatic.com.ni/... to http://www.blandonmoreno.com/... );
- Now click on **Update** button

  I think this should help you!

Comment: Thanks You @lenon ! I going to set up the API KEY, may be the anonymous call to google map api does not work on the new Hosting, I going to try setting the API Key and adding the Origin, I´ll come back to post the results, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HI @lenon sorry for this too late reply but I think is gonna be useful for other people; the issue was with the starter function for google maps, I was starting the script in the body tag with the window onload function, so the multisite hosting modify the body tag and the map doesnt start, I insert the starter function into the end of the map script in the head section and working again. Thanks again for your help.